# How to find x and y coordinates of GeoPoint in android

Tags: android, google-maps

How can we change the GeoPoint in android map view to Points x and y.I did not find any code regarding this.Please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MapView` class can map the `GeoPoint` to actual screen coordinates like this:

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
Point ptScreenCoords = new Point();
mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point, ptScreenCoords);
```

Similarly you can create `GeoPoint` from screen coordinates:

```
GeoPoint point = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(x, y);
```